# c# JavaScriptSerializer deserialize variable type field

Tags: c#, serialization, javascriptserializer

I am trying to deserialize JSON strings where some fields can be different. 
These are some of the strings I have to deserialize:

> {"field1":{"array":[1,2,3]},"field2":{"array":["a","b","c"]}}
>
> {"field1":"", "field2":""}
>
> {"field1":"","field2":{"array":["a","b","c"]}}
>
> {"field1":{"array":[1,2,3]},"field2":""}

The first string is successfully deserialized, but the remainder throws an exception.

Is it possible to parse the four strings with the same code?

Comment: Could you show your efforts so far?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the others are throwing an exception is most likely because your deserialization target data type is expecting an object inside field1 and field2, but in last three, you have empty strings.

Try replacing the empty strings with just `null`.

Comment: The strings came from a webservice, for this reason I can not change the emty strings in null values. I can use string manipulation, of course; but there is the risk of changing somothing else too.

Comment: In that case, I advise showing your deserialization code and I'll reproduce the problem.  Remember to use the code formatting tools as well; as good presentation on stackoverflow will ensure you receive assistance.